# Comando de Github CLI no es reconocido por el cmd

Tags: python, github, cli

estoy aprendiendo a usar repositorios de GitHub y quiero usar un CLI disponible para descargar un conjunto de imágenes de una base de datos. El problema está en que, aunque logro instalar el paquete del CLI (https://github.com/ImageMarkup/isic-cli) con el comando `pip install isic-cli`, no consigo ejecutar el comando `isic` puesto que se me indica que no es reconocido como un comando interno o externo en el cmd.

> C:\Users\Usuario>isic user login
> "isic" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Las instalaciones del Git y el GitHub CLI se han hecho todas en la ruta por defecto. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Eso es un problema con las variables de entorno

Para configurar las variables de entorno(cuando en el CLI no reconoce un comando)

1. Buscar el archivo .exe que ejecuta el programa Copiar dirección de
   barra de rutas Poner en el buscador de windows "variables de entorno
   del sistema"
2. Seleccionar la opción variables de entorno.
3. Seleccionar la opción "PATH" de la variables de sistema y de
   usuario.
4. Darle a editar
5. Darle a nuevo y pegar al final la ruta copiada anteriormente
6. Darle "aceptar" a todas las ventanas que se abrieron.

*En algunos casos pide reiniciar la PC.